# Unable to remove user from aws organization

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations

**Background**
I wants to split an EC2 billing because I am having new project. Then I create a new AWS user in the organization. The creation seems very normal. However, when I finish create according to the UI. It has no any password confirmation to me. Therefore new user is a broken one because it is incomplete registration.

**Step to reproduce:**
[image: Click Add Account]
[image: Fill in the form]
[image: Perform delete]
[image: None of them works]
[image: No one works]

Becomes chicken and egg problem. Because my registration for the new user in my organization is not complete yet. But in order to remove it I have to login it first!

**Questions:**
1. How to complete my 2nd user registration?
2. How to remove my 2nd user in my organization?
3. Is it correct that 2nd user will see his own EC2 billing only in his budget explorer?

**Update:**
@Aress Support
After enter correct email and capcha

[image: After enter capcha]

Comment: Removing an account is not the same as deleting an account. You can remove an account from your organization only if the account has the information that is required for it to operate as a standalone account. Aside from contacting AWS Support, I think you'd have to sign into the new account using the link shown in your last image.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new member account, Organizations sets an initial password that cannot be retrieved. To access the account as a root user, follow the account recovery process.

- Go to the sign-in page of the AWS console at
  https://console.aws.amazon.com/, and choose Forgot your password?
- Enter the email address of the member account.
- After you receive the reset password email, choose the reset password
  link.
- After resetting the password, one can sign in to the AWS Management
  Console using the new password.

According to AWS Docs before removing an account from an organization, you should know the following:

> You can remove an account from your organization only if the account
>   has the information that is required for it to operate as a standalone
>   account.

For more information on Billing Access, refer the following documentation.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/grantaccess.html

Comment: I have followed your answer. I stuck at first step. Please see my updated question.

Comment: New user account is not a root for sure. Then the reset password supposed to not work.

Answer (score 0):

First I have to make an organization and assign my new user to it.
After that mark `enable` policy to the organization. Then assign new user to the organization unit. Finally try `forget` password. This time AWS will allow you to login and voilà

[image: Make simple organization]